# Adding new contact with photo to contact database Android

Tags: android

I want to create a Contact example in Android.
I have had a problem when I try to add the contact with a photo.
No error happened, but I can't show a photo that I have added when I using native (default) Contact app of android.

**Here is my code:**

```
if (bitmap != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        op = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.MIMETYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray());
        //op.withYieldAllowed(true);
        ops.add(op.build());

        try {
            stream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this example](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/programatically-adding-contacts-with-photo-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/). It is same like yours but it can add photo successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.
I have found mistake in my code above:
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.MIMETYPE
The right is ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE